# How to set discount at appstore?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I am setting  discount for first 100 customers of my app at app store , is there a way to set discount for specific number of users at app store?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: ok but needs answer if you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

You can change the price for a limited time but there is no way to limit it for a specific number of downloads.

The only way I can really think to do this is by issuing promo codes for your first fifty customers. Apple would object if you wanted to charge for them of course and note that applications downloaded this way are not able to write reviews in the App Store.